# SQL Server to concatenate query results and insert the into another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table `A` and a table `B`. Table `A` contains the product data, Table `B` contains the images for each product. One line per image.

I need a SQL statement created to Loop through table `A`, get the product ID, then concatenate the result set and insert it into one field in table `A`.

`Table A`:

```
P-ID, Value1, Value2, Value3,    ImageLocation
35    Name    Price   description
```

Table `B`:

```
P-ID, ImageLocation
35    /upload/directory/imagename.jpg
35    /upload/directory/imagename2.jpg
35    /upload/directory/imagename3.jpg
```

End result:

```
TableA:
P-ID, Value1, Value2, Value3,       ImageLocation
35    Name    Price   description   /up/dir/image.jpg,/up/dir/image2.jpg,/up/dir/image3.jpg
```

How on earth do I SQL-ize this?

Thanks from the newbie!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multivalued columns are frowned upon... and there's not a graceful way to do this in Sql Server - but, you can use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT PID, Value1, Value2, Value3, STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + ImageLocation
  FROM TableB b
  WHERE b.PID = a.PID
  FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') AS ImageLocation
FROM TableA a
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50c61/1)

But again, do you really need to be doing this in your Sql query, or is this something that you can handle in your application / presentation?

Comment: Yes I am trying to write a sql statement to extract data into an excel for importing into another system... I just need one query and to save the results into a spreadsheet... It's not for an ongoing system.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something along these lines:

```
Select p.id, location || '/' ||......
From
(
Select * from tableA a, tableB b
Where a.id = b.id
)
```

I don't know which DBMS you are using, so please see which string con. is appropriate

Comment: For **Microsoft SQL Server 2008** (as mentioned in the question and its tag) - the string concatenation operator would be `+`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the SQL Server tag, missed it somehow. Also, i know it is frowned upon to use old JOINS, but seems that every beginners book teaches it that way, just seemed easier to explain that way.